# Storing data structure (set) as a file but not loading it into memory

Tags: python

I have a 2gb text file for filtering out values used by a python program i access infrequently. I do this by loading every line into a set and doing fast contains checks. This was a good idea at first when the file was only a few megabytes in size, but after a year the file has grown, and the initial loading time has become unmanageable even though i have basically unlimited RAM.

Before i replace my existing code with a file-based binary search, i wanted to ask if there's any way to use set functionality directly as a file on disk? I know there are tools to store data structures and load them into memory, but the loading part is the problem here.

Comment: What you are asking for is a database, `sqlite3` would work, and it comes with Python out of the box so no external dependencies.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is probably what i'll go with to offload the binary search to the db, not sure why i didn't think of it given it was so obvious having used sqlite quite a lot.

Comment: Yeah, don't reinvent the wheel. Just make sure your table is indexed on your search column.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to store it to a database. MongoDB handles sets well. Then you can just query the database like you do a set.

you have to install

```
sudo apt install mongodb-server-core
pip3 install pymongo
And create a /data/db directory on your drive with the right permissions then run
mongod &
before this code will work:
```

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

#client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')


db = client.pymongo_test

posts = db.posts
post_data = {
    'title': 'Python and MongoDB',
    'content': 'PyMongo is fun, you guys',
    'author': 'Bill'
}
result = posts.insert_one(post_data)
print('One post: {0}'.format(result.inserted_id))

bills_post = posts.find_one({'author': 'Bill'})
print(bills_post)

One post: 5dc61c0cc2b75ebc458da31f
{'_id': ObjectId('5dc61bf76071bde943ca262b'), 'title': 'Python and MongoDB', 'content': 'PyMongo is fun, you guys', 'author': 'Bill'}
``
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this as an interim approach until you find a DB or indexed file solution.

1. Divide the keyword file into multiple files(37), based on the character the keyword starts with. e.g.

   - keys_startwith_a.txt /contains all values starting with 'A' or 'a'
     ...
   - keys_startwith_z.txt /contains all values starting with 'Z' or 'z'
   - keys_startwith_0.txt /contains all values starting with '0'

     ...
   - keys_startwith_9.txt /contains all values starting with '9'
   - keys_startwith_others.txt /contains all values starting with any other char
2. change the read mechanism for each file as stream. e.g.

io.read(file, buffer=1)

Now if you want to compare values, you just have to check the char the key starts with and compare against the values in corresponding file.

With this

- Your file loading is faster(each file footprint should be significantly reduced) and on demand(stream) i.e. only when required
- comparison is faster since check is against less no of values.
- since you have unlimited memory, even if all the files are loaded during comparison, it . won't create issues.
- Finally, you can perhaps use threads for even faster loading of files and can pass on the comparison tasks to multiple threads(if required)